# mount Vue apps into container of main Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to create a base Vue app providing basic functionality like signing in, navigating through a sidebar etc. But the navbar items have to be interchangeable. I want to create separate Vue apps representing these navbar items.

---

**Basic idea:**
A REST API and a basic container (Vue app), which is able to render other Vue apps in a specifc `div` element, should be provided. This would allow other ones to add their own frontend apps and work with that API if they want to. So I will just provide some basic apps. The main idea is to create a **Plug and Play system** for a very modular administration system. I will provide a registration process for that custom app so the API knows that app and it's base url and my base app can fetch all those apps.

[image]

---

**Base app setup**

So my base app provides a route for these custom apps

```
{
  path: '/app/*',
  component: CustomAppContainer,
},
```

and will render this view

```
<template>
  <div id="customAppContainer">Render custom apps here</div>
</template>
```

and my navbar could provide the link `/app/one` to navigate and render the app called 'one' in that `customAppContainer`.

---

**Custom app setup**

When defining my routes I have to set the `base` url

```
export default new Router({
  base: '/one/',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
    },
  ],
});
```

but for the **main.js** I am not sure how to set it up. I think I have to update this to something like

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(CustomAppContainer),
}).$mount('#customAppContainer');
```

but obviously this app doesn't know `CustomAppContainer` and `#customAppContainer`.

---

Further I'm thinking about the distribution when I only have some `index.html` files and want to integrate one into another. So how could I deploy a base app and when the user wants to access a custom app via `/app/myCustomApp` I mount the custom app into the `customAppContainer` ?

A similiar example would be [Nextcloud](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/developer_manual/app/index.html)

When developing a new Vue app I can run it as a standalone application. But for production I want to take the files from the dist folder and put them into a `apps` directory and when running my base container application it knows about all those sub-apps on start.

Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: why not creating all that functionality in a private npm package that you can simply import into your new projects?

Comment: sorry, I don't want to import that app container into new projects. I want to create new projects and attach their index.html to the app containers index.html

Comment: I think Balexandre is right. You have a project and the project contains modules. Your modules are stand alone vue apps, possibly even containing an index page with routing and all, that live inside the main project. So your container for sub apps sounds more like a place where you would inject dependencies in the form of the modules I described. A modules is a new project. What exactly do you mean by saying 'attach their index.html to the app containers index.html'? This sounds a little like you are thinking in a way or format you learned elsewhere while an NPM package is the solution here.

Comment: Thanks but I am really not sure. Maybe a new sub-app is not made with Vue, Angular or React, maybe it's just a single `.html` file so it would be the best to have a `apps` directory and put all those apps into that directory.. Then I could render each app within an IFrame although using IFrames would be a bad solution. When using npm packages I would have to publish each app to npm, and maybe other ones use yarn or nothing like this because they just want to create a .html file with some Jquery..

Answer (score 3):

#### 1

> *Vue does not know `CustomAppContainer`*

Try to add `import CustomAppContainer from "path/to/CustomAppContainer.vue"`
It must be in .vue file.

---

#### 2

> *Vue does not know `#customAppContainer`*

Yes, that selector must be in `index.html`. Yours is in `CustomAppContainer`.
Try to add to `index.html` (usually in /public folder) something like `<div id="#app"></div>` and replace `.$mount('#customAppContainer');` with `.$mount('#app');`

---

#### 3

Vue router needs `<router-view>` tag. So, try this markup:

```html
<!-- In template is all page -->
<template>
  <!-- Some stuff as navigation... -->
  <nav>
    <!-- Router links - renders as "a" element -->
    <router-link to="/one">To /one</router-link>
    <!-- Or use standard tags - they're also good -->
    <a href="/two">To /two</a>
  </nav>
  <!-- In this component would be component chosen in router (Home.vue) -->
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

---

#### 4

Router.js needs import:

```js
import Home from "path/to/the/Home.vue"
export default new Router({
  base: '/one/',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
    },
  ],
});
```

---

All is good?