# Redirect on startup by the given browser URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I created a new Vue app with a base path. Due to the fact the app is embedded into another Vue app, this app doesn't render the `router-view` on startup. If you want to know more about how or why this app is embedded into another app, please have a look here:

[mount Vue apps into container of main Vue app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131480/mount-vue-apps-into-container-of-main-vue-app)

and my own answer to this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58265830/9945420

When starting my application, it renders everything except the `router-view`. I want to redirect on startup by the given browser URL. This is my **router** config:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import One from './views/One.vue';
import Two from './views/Two.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    base: '/my-embedded-app/',
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: One,
        },
        {
            path: '/two',
            component: Two,
        },
    ],
});

router.replace(router.currentRoute.fullPath);

export default router;
```

I want the app to render the component **Two** when calling `.../my-embedded-app/two`. Unfortunately, `router.replace` always redirects to `/` (so the browser URL is `.../my-embedded-app/`). I debugged the `router`, and saw that the path is `/`, but I would expect it to be `/two`.

**Important note:** 
I don't want to redirect the user to `/two` whenever the url is `/`. I just want to render the view `Two` when the url is `/two`. Currently it doesn't.

What might be wrong? Maybe I don't even need that redirect, and can solve the problem a more elegant way.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to render component One when you write - /my-embedded-app/one as URL and component Two for - /my-embedded-app/two? If yes, did you try -  {
            path: 'two',
            component: Two,
        } 
Removing '/' from '/two'

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tried your approach but then I get a warning that this route has to use a leading slash. When running the application this route didn't work then..

Comment: can you change the order of your route?

Answer (score 1):

updated: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/variablevasas/q9w2xva8/2/)

What wound up happening is that `route.currentRoute.fullPath` was executed before router was ready.

Comment: That didn't change anything. `router.currentRoute.fullPath` still returns `/` instead of `/two` when calling `localhost:3000/apps/my-embedded-app/two`

Comment: try `router.onReady(() => {
  router.replace(router.currentRoute.fullPath);
});`

Comment: sorry that didn't work. When I use the onReady event I even get this error `message: "Navigating to current location ("/subApps/app-one") is not allowed"`

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 i suggest you make a jsfiddle and explain exactly what you need and may be people can change it for you, we cant exactly reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce this with a fiddle. A fileserver is required for the IFrame container. But this is a repository for testing purposes https://github.com/byteCrunsher/router-startup

Comment: will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal behavior, it is the way single page application works. The "pound" - like # - sign means that the links will not move the application to another page.

so you can change the router mode to

```
mode:"hash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `beforeEnter`. Have a look at the below code:

```
const router = new Router({
  base: "/my-embedded-app/",
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: One,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // Your are free to add whatever logic here.
        // On first visit
        next("/two");
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/two",
      component: Two
    }
  ]
});
```

Read more about Navigation guards [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard)

Comment: sorry, same for tony19's answer. I don't want to redirect the user. I want to render the `Two` view if the browser url is `.../two`. Currently it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a github repo or some to test the actual?

Otherwise my first idea is to use children routes with an "empty" view as base, here an example about what I tried. (working in my case)

**router.js**

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/my-embedded-app/',
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'base',
        component: Base,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            name: 'one',
            component: One
          },
          {
            path: 'two',
            name: 'two',
            component: Two
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
})
```

**Base.vue**

```
<template>
    <router-view/>
</template>
```

**One.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>One</div>
</template>
```

**Two.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>Two</div>
</template>
```

Comment: This problem is related to this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58397766/update-initial-router-url-when-running-inside-iframe-object-tags and I created a small repository for testing purposes https://github.com/byteCrunsher/router-startup