# update initial router url when running inside iframe / object tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, vue.js

I'm currently rendering Vue apps inside object tags (iframe could work too) of a container/master Vue app. First I setup a fileserver serving that container or the requested sub-app to render inside the div.

For the sake of simplicity I will only show the required routing of my Node/Express server

```
// serve the sub-app on demand
router.get('/subApps/:appName', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `../apps/${req.params.appName}/index.html`);
});

// always render the app container if no sub-app was requested
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../base/index.html'));
});
```

My app container / master Vue app is inside the view file rendered on `/apps/:appName`, requests that sub-app and wraps it into object tags

```
  document.getElementById("customAppContainer").innerHTML = `<object style="width: 100%; height:100%;" data="http://localhost:3000/subApps/${appKey}"></object>`;
```

This approach works fine but the rendered sub-app uses the startup url `http://localhost:3000/subApps/app-one` although it should use the url `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one`. When the sub-app loads the router instance I have to change the startup url from the iframe url to the browser url (parent).

I thought about fixing that with `history.replaceState`

```
const router = new Router({ ... });

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = to.path;
});

if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
    const browserUrl = top.location.href;
    history.replaceState(null, null, browserUrl);
}

export default router;
```

Why do I want to do this? The *App.vue* of the master app should append the sub-app route to the browser url. With this approach it's possible to update the browser url while navigating inside the sub-app. I achieve this by storing the sub-app url to the local storage and listen for local storage changes at the master app side. So the **App.vue** file uses this code

```
<script>
export default {
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
      const fullRoute = this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath;
      const routeSegments = fullRoute.split("/");
      const appsIndex = routeSegments.indexOf("apps");
      const newBaseUrlSegments = routeSegments.slice(0, appsIndex + 2);
      const newBaseUrl = newBaseUrlSegments.join("/");
      const subAppRoute = localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate;
      const updatedUrl = newBaseUrl.concat(subAppRoute);
      history.replaceState(null, null, updatedUrl);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

to enable a routing while using IFrames. It almost works, this is what I get

[image]

Unfortunately it happens that when calling `/` of the sub-app the browser url gets updated to

> http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/apps/app-one

although I'm expecting

> http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/

---

**Reproduction:**

I created a [repository](https://github.com/byteCrunsher/reproduction) for reproduction / testing. Does someone know what might be wrong or how to fix that url updating?

---

**Update:**

I think the error occurs because in the *router.js* of the subApp I'm firing this code

```
if (window.location !== window.parent.location) {
    const browserUrl = top.location.href;
    history.replaceState(null, null, browserUrl);
}

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    console.log({ urlToAppend: to.path });
    localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = to.path;
});
```

The replaceState function will update the IFrame url from `/subApps/app-one` to the correct browser url `/apps/app-one`. Unfortunately this will trigger the afterEach event and `to.path` results in `/apps/app-one` although it should be `/`.

If the url would be `/apps/app-one/users/create` the after each event should trigger with `/users/create` of course.

But I didn't figured out how to fix this first triggered event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It may be a bit hacky solution but it works for me. Just check that current url path is not equal to `to.path` in case if event is triggered twice</strike>

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    console.log({ urlToAppend: to.path });
    if (router.currentRoute.path !== to.path) {
        localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = to.path;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

In `base/src/App.vue` in storage event listener before concatenating sub route to base route you don't check for the possible duplicates. This fix should help

```js
window.addEventListener("storage", () => {
      const fullRoute = this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath;
      const routeSegments = fullRoute.split("/");
      const appsIndex = routeSegments.indexOf("apps");
      const newBaseUrlSegments = routeSegments.slice(0, appsIndex + 2);
      const newBaseUrl = newBaseUrlSegments.join("/");
      const subAppRoute = localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate;
      if (subAppRoute.startsWith(newBaseUrl)) {
        history.replaceState(null, null, newBaseUrl);
      } else {
        const updatedUrl = newBaseUrl.concat(subAppRoute);
        history.replaceState(null, null, updatedUrl);
      }
    });
```

And `router.afterEach` should look like this to navigate to subRoutes which are defined within app-one router:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
        const newPath = '/' + to.path.split('/').pop();
        const matchingRoutes = router.options.routes.filter(r => r.path === newPath);
        const isPathInRoutes = matchingRoutes.length > 0;
        if (router.currentRoute.path !== newPath && isPathInRoutes) {
            router.push(newPath);
            localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = newPath;
        } else {
            localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = to.path;
        }
});
```

If you want page one to be rendered by default when user goes to `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one` you could check whether last part of the entered url is equal to sub apps base route(`/app-one`) and if it does navigate to default page route(`/`):

```js
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    let newPath = '/' + to.path.split('/').pop();
    const matchingRoutes = router.options.routes.filter(r => r.path === newPath);
    const isPathInRoutes = matchingRoutes.length > 0;
    if (newPath === router.history.base || !isPathInRoutes) {
        newPath = '/';
    }
    if (router.currentRoute.path !== newPath) {
            router.push(newPath);
            localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = newPath;
    } else {
            localStorage.subAppRouteUpdate = to.path;
    }
});
```

Comment: @ ktad thanks for your reply. I tested your code and yes this fixes the initial error but when I then navigate to a subroute of the embedded app the url browser url never updates...

Comment: so if you navigate to `App 1 - Page 2` the browser url still is `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one` but I would expect `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/two`

Comment: :( well .. there was an attempt +1

Comment: Can you check whether my updated answer is working as intended?

Comment: yes, you almost got it! :) The last problem I have is when calling this url `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one` the sub app will not render the view `One`. Same for `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/two` where I would expect it to render `Two` .. :/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. Does my new update solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately it changed nothing. I also noticed a second problem. If you navigate to app 2 (just a html file https://github.com/byteCrunsher/reproduction/blob/master/apps/app-two/index.html ) the anchor links won't update the url anymore :(

Comment: Nvm obviously the app 2 does not update the localstorage when navigating so of course the url will not update .. my bad. @ ktad unfortunately the router is still not rendering the correct vue file on startup

Comment: @ ktad I rewarded you the bounty :) the rendering of a page is still missing tho

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 Thank you! I've just cloned your repo again into the new folder to check whether my second update will work, and it does. Could you check it again? Maybe you forgot to build app-one project or forgot to copy its distributed files to other directory?

Comment: I've also updated my answer so that page 1 is rendered by default when user navigates to `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one`

Comment: thanks and sorry for the late response. Yes, this code works for the first page rendering but when calling `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/two` for example the code will still render the first page. I think this line `newPath = '/';` needs to get fixed.

Comment: Basically app one should always render the correct page on startup :)

Comment: When I call `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/two` App 1 - Page 2 is rendered. Can you open this url in incognito mode? Maybe your browser cached old version. And this part `newPath = '/';` is only fired when user calls `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one` so it redirects to `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one/` which renders App 1 - Page 1 instead of blank App 1

Comment: @ ktad sorry, I cleared the cache and now it worked fine. When I call `http://localhost:3000/` then click on `App 1` it will render the first page. When I then click on the `App 1 - Page 2` link it will render page 2. When I then click that `App 1` link above again it will update the browser url back to `http://localhost:3000/apps/app-one` but I would expect it to render the first page .. no =?

Comment: if you would like to see the current code I'm using I updated the repo :) https://github.com/byteCrunsher/reproduction/blob/master/apps/app-one/src/router.js